# Discrete Math: Recurrence Relations Explanation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I was looking over one of the solutions for one of my homework assignments and was a little confused as to how they factored part of the solution.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afjTI.png)

(I don't have enough posts to embed the image in the question)

I'm a little confused as to how they turned this

$8((n-1)4^{n-1}))-16((n-2)4^{n-2}))$

into

$(n-1)2^3(2^{2n-2})-(n-2)2^4(2^{2n-4})$

Could anyone explain this to me a little better?

Comment: There's no picture in the solution link

Comment: I apologize, it's there it's just hard to see against the black background, If you download the image you should be able to see it. I'm gonna see if I can upload it on a white background

Comment: You were able to type two equations in MathJax, you should be able to convert the image to MathJax.  Please do so as a courtesy to those who would like to help you answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that

$8=2\cdot2\cdot2=2^3$

$16=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2=2^4$

$4^{n-1}=(2\cdot2)^{n-1}=(2^2)^{n-1}=2^{2(n-1)}=2^{2n-2}$.

$4^{n-2}=(2\cdot2)^{n-2}=(2^2)^{n-2}=2^{2(n-2)}=2^{2n-4}$.

using these identities you get the desired result.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!!